# Need a regular expression to split string in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split

I need some help with regular expressions in javascript. I've got a string like:

```
var S = '["abc","defg", "hij"]';
```

How could I split it in javascript to get `a[0]=abc`, `a[1]=defg`, `a[2]=hij`?
Because `var a = S.split(',');` just give me `a[0]=["abc"` and so on.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Learn to use quotes properly, It would be better if you define your string as `var s = '["abc","defg", "hij"]';`

Comment: I don't see how the above code line works? there are unescaped quotes in the string... please edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you fix the quotes you use to delimit the string, then you can `JSON.parse` the string to an array and work with it as you need, like this:

```js
var s = '["abc","defg", "hij"]';
var arr = JSON.parse(s);

console.log(arr);
console.log(arr[0]); // = 'abc'
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's it

Answer (score 0):

If you mean:

```
var S = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
```

Then use `S[0], S[1] and S[2].`

If you mean:

```
var S = "[\"abc\", \"def\", \"ghi\"]";
```

Then use [JSON parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Complete example:

```
var S = "[\"abc\", \"def\", \"ghi\"]";
var SParsed = JSON.parse(S);
alert(SParsed [1]); //def
```